# Probability of one person winning in a four-way game of rock paper scissors

Tags: probability

There are four distinct people playing RPS: A, B, C, and D.

What is the probability that  A wins? (this includes joint victories).

I know I'm encouraged to show my work but I literally don't know where to start. All I know is that there are $3^4$ total possibilities since everybody gets 3 choices.

Comment: Can you tell us the rules of four-way RPS? I only know how to play classical two-way RPS.

Comment: If rock, paper, and scissors all come out simultaneously, who wins?

Comment: If everybody dishes out the same sign then nobody wins.

Comment: You need to specify who wins for each combination of choices.  Until we know the rules nobody can answer.

Comment: For example if A, B, and C go for paper and D goes for scissors, D is the sole winner. If A and B go for rock, C and D go for paper, then C and D both win. Hope that was clear enough :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that "winning" this 4-way version of rock paper scissors involves a player simply not losing to anyone else then we can work towards solving the problem using the law of total probability. Consider the probability of winning given that a player (e.g. player A) has chosen a type.
$$P(Win) = P(Win | Rock)P(Rock) + P(Win | Paper)P(Paper) + P(Win | Scissors) P(Scissors) = 3 P(Win | Rock) P(Rock)$$
The probability to win given that you've chosen rock for instance is now simply the probability that everyone else has chosen either Scissors or Rock. For each individual player the probability of Scissors or Rock is $\dfrac{2}{3}$. However, we have to subtract the one case where everyone chooses rock as this is a tie. So in the end we get $P(Win|Rock) = (\dfrac{2}{3})^3 - \dfrac{1}{3^3} = \dfrac{8}{27} - \dfrac{1}{3^3} = \dfrac{7}{27}$. Thus, the probability of a player winning is $P(Win) = 3 P(Win | Rock) P(Rock) = 3(\dfrac{7}{27})(\dfrac{1}{3}) = \dfrac{7}{27}$